# Oracle text with multiple phrases and Boolean logic

Tags: oracle12c, oracle-text

Am I doing it right? I am querying records that **must** contain exact phrase `"buy now"` and must contain one of the following

- exact phrase `"lonely beach"` or
- both words `backpackers` and `camping`

  SELECT *
  FROM Table1
  WHERE contains(Text ,'buy now')                           >0
  AND contains(Text ,'(lonely beach) OR (backpackers and camping)')>0

Can this query be simplified to one `CONTAINS`? How about brackets? Am I using them right?

Comment: The query seems correct (as far as I can tell - I tested it and it works exactly as written). I doubt that you can check for two conditions in a single `CONTAINS`.

Comment: OK so no curly braces here?

Comment: It worked for me with no curly braces. Why do you need to ask - don't you have a test system to check yourself?

Comment: I am asking about the optimal way to do this. I have the docs of course and tested on my server but I am just doing a reality check